# Using GDAL for reading calibration and annotation data set

Tags: gdal, annotation, sar

I have a Sentinel-1 .SAFE data which provides a wealth of information through .tiff images and also .xml files containing annotation and calibration information.

Following the instructions in the related [manual](https://sentinel.esa.int/documents/247904/685163/S1-Radiometric-Calibration-V1.0.pdf) document, I know that there are four lookup tables (LUT) related to each image which provides necessary information for converting the radar reflectivity into physical units (sigma-naught, gamma-naught, beta-naught and DN). By opening the relative .xml files I can see these information.

I wonder if there is a GDAL method/function implemented for easy extraction of these information from the respective annotation/calibration .xml files?

Answer (score 1):

I Think I found the answer to my question.

[GDAL](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/safe.html) says : Currently the (SAR) driver does not apply calibration information.

Comment: Raster_calculator.py from GDAL should let you rescale and offset manually. You can probably write a command line script to read the xml and process the .SAFE file.